# Is a Spring Data (JPA) Repository thread-safe? (aka is SimpleJpaRepository thread safe)

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using a [Spring Data (JPA) repository](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.core-concepts) to take care of CRUD boilerplate.

I define my repository interface like so:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, Long>
{
  public Foo findByXAndYAndZ(X x, Y y, Z z);
}
```

Spring then auto-magically generates me an implementation of said interface.  What we get back is a proxy, but I believe that eventually we get down to a `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository`.

A `JdkDynamicAopProxy` is thread-safe *if* the underlying target class is thread-safe.  The question therefore is: is `SimpleJpaRepository` thread safe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, yes. It's assuming a managed `EntityManager` which we'll either obtain from Spring's factory classes (in case you're using Spring as container) or as a CDI managed bean (declared through an `@Producer` method).

Comment: Hi Oliver - thanks for this.  Can I ask though - is this documented somewhere? Do you have any references?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this "managed" `EntityManager` makes `SimpleJpaRepository` thread safe?

Comment: I'd argue this is a simple consequence from the way an `EntityManager` is specified to behave in JPA. It is not thread safe by default, thus it needs to be managed (read: correctly bound to a thread and proxied to point to the thread-bound instance). In Spring this is achieved through the use of a `SharedEntityManagerCreator`. In the CDI case, the container will do that for you.

Comment: Oliver, do you have an example of using the SharedEntityManagerCreator like you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Generally Spring wired objects are thread safe.

Here are some helpful links:

http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-two-crud/

Make sure you use the correct Transaction manager with it

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html

Comment: Hi Tim - I didn't find anything about thread safety in [that article](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-two-crud/). Did I miss it?

Comment: what do you mean by "Spring wired objects"? If I creates a class and define a bean of that class in web app context, than that bean is a singleton by default that is not thread safe. I should handle the thread safety for that bean by myself, Spring won't manage thread safety for the bean even it is wired.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive yet, I could totally be wrong, but I don't think repositories are thread safe IN SPECIFIC CASES.  Take a look at:

RepositoryFactorySupport.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor in spring-data-commons on github.

There is a concurrent hashmap containing methods -> queries.  If those queries contain state, or any properties of those queries contain state, then the repository is no longer thread safe.  A good example would be spring-data-neo4j.  DerivedGraphRepositoryQuery specifically has issues since it contains CypherFinderQuery's.  THOSE contain state in the form of parameters to the queries.  I BELIEVE it's possible to have a race condition where a parameter is overwritten by another thread during a query in DerivedGraphRepository.  This could happen in other spring data repositories if the authors of the query objects give them state.