# Regarding Spring JpaRepository method thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I was curious whether spring jparepository methods are thread safe and then I read the stackflow article ([Is a Spring Data (JPA) Repository thread-safe? (aka is SimpleJpaRepository thread safe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965735/is-a-spring-data-jpa-repository-thread-safe-aka-is-simplejparepository-threa)). From there, I understood that repository methods are thread safe and then I made one POC to test the thread safety. I made one repository say FormRepository to do CRUD operations for 'form' entity, that is extending the JpaRepository. From DAO, I simply invoked 100 threads making the form object and manually setting its id and then saving the 'form' object.

Below is the code for reference:-

```
@Repository
public interface FormRepository extends JpaRepository<Tbldynamicform, Long>     {

Tbldynamicform save(Tbldynamicform tblform);

@Query("SELECT max(tblform.formid) FROM Tbldynamicform tblform")
Optional<Integer> findMaxId();

}
......End of Repository above and start of DAO below...

@Component
public class DynamicFormDAO implements DynamicFormDAO {

@Inject
private FormRepository formRepository;

public void testThreadSafety() throws Exception {
    List<Callable<Integer>> tasks = new ArrayList<>(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        tasks.add(() -> {
            try {

                Tbldynamicform tbldynamicform = new Tbldynamicform();//Set  all the required fields for form
                if (tbldynamicform.getFormid() == null)
                    tbldynamicform.setFormid(findFormID());
                Tbldynamicform form = formRepository.save(tbldynamicform);
                return form.getFormid();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    executor.invokeAll(tasks);

}

private int findFormID() throws Exception {
    Optional<Integer> id = formRepository.findMaxId();
    if (id != null && id.isPresent() && id.get() != null) {
        int generatedId = id.get().intValue();
        return ++generatedId;
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

When I do this, I was assuming that things have to work fine because the form repository methods are thread safe but somehow I am getting the sql dataintegrityviolationexception several times in logs making the insertion of several records failure. Below error for reference:-

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.TBLDYNAMICFORM(FORMID)"; SQL statement:
insert into Tbldynamicform (clientid, copyfromexisting, creationdate, formdesc, formmode, formname, formtemplate, formtitle, procutype, status, formid) values (?, ?, ?, ?,...

This has made me to think whether this is the problem of thread safety or some other problem? In my understanding, all the 'tbldynamicform' objects I created in my dao will remain on thread stack. Only the formRepository will be on heap storage and if the formrepository methods are thread safe, 100 records has to be inserted in database without any problem.

If I do the setId and save in synchronized block, everything works ok but that's not my intention and not required if the repository methods are thread safe.

Experts, any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your saving task is not atomic - two threads might fetch the same maximum id before one of them saved the new entity.

And then, even if the save method of the repository is thread - safe, it wont help.

The maxId is thread safe, the save is thread safe, but your method inside the runnable of each thread is not thread safe.

Comment: Yes, that I also thought the same because as I also put in my question that if I put save and findformId in syncronized block, everything works fine..

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, yes, it is threadsafe, but your database is also stateful (obviously) and for integrity to be maintained you may need things like a locking strategy (hold locks to make things synchronous, or use an optimistic strategy and retry where required). As someone has noted in another answer, if you simply used a different method of generating an ID (check out SUID) you code would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from how you retrieve the last ID with findFormID(), it doesn't work in a concurrent context.

What if two threads ask an ID at the same time ? They will retrieve the same ID and create two objects with the same ID. here is your problem.

Some integrated solutions for generated IDs already exist and you should not try to implement your own unless you know what you do.

Comment: "What if two threads ask an ID at the same time" Because findFormID is synchronized, only one thread will be able to get the id. But the problem is that save and setformid is not atomic.