# ConcurrentModificationException in Spring Boot CRUD repository

Tags: spring-boot

This is a theoretical question. I would like to understand the possible reasons of a `ConcurrentModificationException` when using a CRUD repository in Spring Boot.

More precisely, I have a specific question for which I would like a "yes" or "no" answer. Knowing that the exception is sometimes thrown by the line `myRepository.saveAll(myArrayList);`, and that `myRepository` is used, in different threads, by this `saveAll` and by a `findById`, is it possible that parallel execution in different threads of `saveAll` and `findById` could generate such an exception? I hope the answer is "no", but I'm not sure. If the answer is "yes", I would not be clear on how to fix the problem.

If the answer is "no", does it follow that the only circumstance that can sometimes throw this exception is the concurrent use of `myArrayList` in different threads (my code does so), i.e., modification (addition of elements) of `myArrayList` by one thread while `saveAll` is being executed in another thread? If so, would it be enough to enclose the `saveAll` and `myArrayList.add(...)` codes inside a `synchronized (myArrayList) {}`?

For completeness, `myRepository` is an interface that simply extends `CrudRepository`, annotated with `@Repository` and `@Transactional`.

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Even if Spring `CRUDRepository` could be an issue(as far as i know they are `threadsafe`),  it is not safe to work with an instance of `ArrayList` from different threads without synchronizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it possible that parallel execution in different threads of saveAll and findById could generate such an exception

No - these methods are [threadsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965735/is-a-spring-data-jpa-repository-thread-safe-aka-is-simplejparepository-threa/15971952)

> does it follow that the only circumstance that can sometimes throw
> this exception is the concurrent use of myArrayList in different
> threads (my code does so), i.e., modification (addition of elements)
> of myArrayList by one thread while saveAll is being executed in
> another thread?

From your problem statement - the above processing is the most likely cause of the exception you are getting. Having said that - [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) for collections in general can be caused even by single thread. If you modify your collection while you are iterating over it - then throwing this exception is the fail-fast mechanism adopted by implementing collections. For e.g., the below code if run in a single thread would still throw this exception

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList(1, 2, 3);
    for (Integer integer : integers) {
        integers.remove(1);
    }
```

From the documentation of [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) - you can understand it in more details.

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has
> been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread
> issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of
> an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a
> thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the
> collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this
> exception.